# elastic search query in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am having trouble making this URL query work in Java, it does not return any results. but from the browser it returns all the results, here is the URL that returns result:

```
_search?pretty&q=*357*+AND+account_id:574fe92c9179a809fd76f0b8+AND+invalid:false
```

And here is my code (does not return any results):

```
    FilterBuilder[] filtersArray = new FilterBuilder[2];
    filtersArray[0] = FilterBuilders.termFilter("account_id", "574fe92c9179a809fd76f0b8");
    filtersArray[1] = FilterBuilders.termFilter("invalid", false);
    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery("*357*"), FilterBuilders.andFilter(filtersArray));
    SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch(SecurityManager.getNamespace())
            .addSort("created_time", SortOrder.DESC)
            .setTypes(dataType)
            .setQuery(query)
            .addFields("_id")
            .setFrom(page * size)
            .setSize(size)
            .setExplain(false)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

Can someone tell me what is the best way to translate the URL query into a java query?

Comment: In your URL query `&account_id=574fe92c9179a809fd76f0b8&invalid=false` will have no effect at all, I think you want this instead: `q=*357* +AND+account_id:574fe92c9179a809fd76f0b8+AND+invalid:false`. Check your results and you'll see that you have documents with a different `account_id` and `invalid` values.

Comment: OK sorry for the mistake but even after I put it in the ay mentioned I still get a total of 2256 hits, but nothing in JAVA driver :/

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the URL query you should use is this one

```
?q=*357*+AND+account_id:574fe92c9179a809fd76f0b8+AND+invalid:false
```

otherwise you'll have no constraint on `account_id` and `invalid`

Then, the exact translation of this new URL query in Java is

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*357* AND account_id:574fe92c9179a809fd76f0b8 AND invalid:false");
SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch(SecurityManager.getNamespace())
        .addSort("created_time", SortOrder.DESC)
        .setTypes(dataType)
        .setQuery(query)
        .addFields("_id")
        .setFrom(page * size)
        .setSize(size)
        .setExplain(false)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Notes:

- `queryStringQuery` and not `simpleQueryStringQuery`
- no filters as they are all in the query string already